# Can I change the setting of command line in the current process from Java code?

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I am developing a Java code. Now I need to use a REST function for translation with command line and I need to bring the standard out from it to Java code. 
My problem is that I cannot get correct Japanese words from the REST function because character code of the command line is inappropriate for Japanese.

The followings are the example code.

```
private String getFirstLineOfStdOut(Process p) {

    String first_line_value = "";
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try {
        first_line_value = br.readLine();  // because it is one line output.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return first_line_value;
}

public void runCommandLine(String[] commands) {

    ProcessBuilder pb_check_char_code = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    Process process_check_char_code = null;
    try {
        process_check_char_code = pb_check_char_code.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        process_check_char_code.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String result = getFirstLineOfStdOut(process_check_char_code);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

I run the following code.

```
    runCommandLine(new String[]{"C:\\Windows\\System32\\chcp.com"});
    runCommandLine(new String[]{"C:\\Windows\\System32\\chcp.com", "65001"});
    runCommandLine(new String[]{"sudo_translate_function", "English", "to", "Japanese", "hello"});
    runCommandLine(new String[]{"C:\\Windows\\System32\\chcp.com"});
```

And their results.

```
現在のコード ページ: 932  // It means Active code page: 932
Active code page: 65001
壊れた文字                  // broken words because of the inappropriate character code, 932
現在のコード ページ: 932  // It means Active code page: 932
```

The appropriate words should be "こんにちは" but not to be "壊れた文字".
I am afraid that they cannot share the change of character code across sub-process.
What should I do to share the change of character code?
Thank you very much.

Comment: 意味を分からないよ。文字化けか？ If you run it from the command line does it work?

Comment: @Scar Wombat: thank you for commenting. No, it does not return appropriate Japanese characters. But if I set character code by chcp 65001, it works. The problem results from character code used by command line. Now I need to develop java code but I cannot set character code during translation function is running in command line.

Comment: so to sum up, if you use SJIS it does not work, but if you use UTF8 it works?

Comment: Pass `UTF8` into this constructor https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)

Comment: @Scary Wombat: Yes it does.

Comment: @Scary Wombat: thank you very much. Your solution worked!

Comment: Some console applications use the console's current output codepage (as set by chcp.com) when writing to a pipe or file. But others hard code (or have options or environment variables that configure) using ANSI, OEM, UTF-8, or UTF-16. It has to be determined on a case by case basis.

Comment: Also, when you set the console codepage to 65001, remember to set it back to the previous codepage. The console has many bugs with this codepage, depending on the Windows version, and you shouldn't use it to actually write to the console. If you need Unicode, use the wide-character functions such as `WriteConsoleW` (if Java doesn't support this; its support for the Windows console is fundamentally broken). Plus chcp.com also sets the input codepage. The console's multi-byte read (e.g. `ReadFile`, `ReadConsoleA`) is buggy and limited to 7-bit ASCII if the input codepage is set to 65001.